# How to load different AnchorPane in a SplitPane in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

Pretty simple: I created a "vertical" SplitPanel that contains two AnchorPanes. I want to load a different fxml in the right pane, but I don't seem to be able to do so.
I get a Pane from the FXMLLoader:

```
AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(MainMenuController.class.getResource("ContactGrid.fxml"));
```

How can I load this in the right panel?

Comment: It did! I was tryinng to modify the children nodes, and couldn't find the appropiate method (getItems, opossed to getChildren)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

splitpane.getItems().set(1, pane);
getChildren is replaced by getItems